# The more productive passage by the elements std::vector<struct>

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, struct, type-conversion

I have struct, which consist of a 30 elements different type.

```
struct my_struct {
    int name1;
    int name2;
    int name3;
    long long name4;
    string name5;
    //...
    double name32;
    double name33;
};
```

Also, i have vector, where save data(very much data) which have type of a struct `std::vector<my_struct> my_vector;`

Besides, i have so function:

```
char* name_function(char*){
    //...some code
    return char*;//processed value with type char*
}
```

What me need: take every element from vector, then take every value(name1,name2,..., name33) from struct, and then call function to every value, and after it write processing every value in new struct.

How i can see solution:

```
for(int x=0;x<my_vector.size();x++){
    my_struct struct1 = my_vector[x];
    char name1 = (char)struct1.name1;
    struct1.name1 = int(my_function(&name1));
    char name2= (char)struct1.name2;
    struct1.name2 = double(my_function(&name2); //invalid type conversion
    //...
    my_vector[x]=struct1;
}
```

But, it takes a lot of memory, because i have to create many copies of the elements, maybe there is some more optimal solution for this task?

Comment: It appears that you want to apply a function to each value in a collection of values of different types. Function overloading is a nice technique for that. Better more specific advice can probably be given if you elaborate on what your attempted solution is meant to be a solution for.

Comment: Why do you need to pass all data as `char *`, there is something wrong there

Comment: " it takes a lot of memory, because i have to create many copies of the elements": not at all, all you "consume" is the space allocated to `struct1` (which, by the way, is of no use).

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf agree with you, but i can't overloading this function, as it have very complicated algorithm.

@Slava, i use crypto++ (AES), function encrypte have two arguments `stfEncryptor.Put(const char*, unsigned char);` first of this it is a our value, second-it is size value. And in the original version this function in the argument offer so `(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>)`.

Comment: Is your intent to encrypt all fields in the structure ? (If yes, maybe you can encrypt the whole struct in a single go.)

Comment: @Yves Daoust and how can i do this?

Comment: @YvesDaoust no he cannot, there `std::string` there, that would be only possible for POD

Comment: The easiest way I can see to do this is to make a `to_string` function for your `struct`.  You can serialize all of its data into a single string and then you can encrypt that string.  Then you just decrypt the string and and call a `from_string` or overload the stream operators to handle to conversions.

Comment: It may also be nonsense to encrypt the fields in-place, as they become "unusable". Usually, encryption is made before transmission, which may require a different formatting.

Comment: @engineer_7 you do not have to overload this function, just do not call it directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to encrypt your data, you would need to write your function properly:

```
void rawencrypt( char *data, size_t size ) // encrypts data in place
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        data[i] ^= 255; // lame xor encryption for example
}

template<typename T>
void encrypt( T &data ) { rawencrypt( static_cast<char *>( &data ), sizeof( T ) ); }
```

but for `std::string` it must be specialized:

```
template<>
void encrypt( std::string &data ) { rawencrypt( data.data(), data.length() ); }
```

and you must specialize `encrypt()` for any non POD data that you intend to encrypt. Encrypting your struct in place would be trivial now:

```
for(my_struct& s : my_vector){
    encrypt( s.name1 );
    encrypt( s.name2 );  
    //...
}
```

or you can even specialiize `encrypt()` for `my_struct`:

```
template<>
void encrypt( my_struct &data ) 
{ 
      encrypt( data.name1 );
      encrypt( data.name2 );
      ...
}
```

and loop would become even simpler:

```
for(my_struct& s : my_vector)
    encrypt( s );
```

or if do not have C++11:

```
for(size_t x=0;x<my_vector.size();x++)
    encrypt( my_vector[x] );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy the elements.  Use references instead, and do proper int/string/int conversion:

```
char buf[28];
for(int x=0;x<my_vector.size();x++){
    my_struct& s = my_vector[x];
    itoa(s.name1, buf, 10);
    buf = myfunction(buf);
    s.name1 = atoi(buf);
    //...
    s.name5 = myfunction(s.name5.c_str());
    //...
}
```

If you have C++11 or later:

```
char buf[28];
for(my_struct& s : my_vector){
    itoa(s.name1, buf, 10);
    //...
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is "proper" conversion, but there is no enough information to suggest proper one

Comment: @Slava: I don't think either. I guess that the OP wants to acces the raw bytes (for encryption).

Comment: @John Zwinck Thanks for the answer, I really did get the type converted, but I'm not yet sure that this solution is right for me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust possible, but to do that size of data must be passed to that func, so still unclear. And it is not possible to do that this way for `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

You can write directly

```
my_vector[x].name1 = int(my_function((char)my_vector[x].name1));
```

but these conversions are highly dubious.